# Use regex to find a string, then use regex to find a new string to replace it with

Tags: ruby, regex, google-maps, nokogiri, kml

I used BatchGeo to create a map from a spreadsheet and then downloaded the KML data, which is:

```
<Placemark>
  <name>?</name>
    <Snippet></Snippet>
    <description><![CDATA[]]></description>
    <styleUrl>#style75</styleUrl>
    <address>1234 Example St Denver, CO 80221</address>
    <Point>
      <coordinates>-121.879364,37.815151,0.000000</coordinates>
    </Point>
</Placemark>
```

When imported back into Google Maps, the points are placed at the correct addresses/coordinates, but the name/descriptor next to each pin on the left sidebar says only "?" instead of displaying the address.

I want to use a regex to find each `"<name>?</name>"`, then use regex to find the NEXT instance of `<address>.*</address>` in the file, then go back and replace the `?` between the `<name>` tags with the `*` that was between the `<address>` tags.

There is a block of code between `<Placemark>` tags for each point, with hundreds of points in total.

Here are the bits and pieces I have so far:

```
newkml = File.open( 'Newkml.txt', 'w' )

def process_line(x)
  unless x == "<name>?</name>"
    # just return the original line
  else
    # Find the next instance of /<address>(.*)<\/address>/
    # Go to the original line
    # Replace it with "<name>#{$1}</name>"
  end
end

File.foreach('Whatever.kml'){|line|} do line.process_line
# Make a new file, copy over all of the lines that aren't <name>?</name>,
# and fix the name lines using the method above
```

UPDATE:  Within the original service (BatchGeo) there is an option to set what information goes inside what KML(XML) Tags, so I created a new map and prevented the problem from occurring in the first place.  Thanks to those who referred me to tools that I can use in the future for this kind of operation.

UPDATE 2:  Trying Mark Thomas's solution.  Here is the code I ran:

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'nokogiri'

doc = Nokogiri::XML("whatever.xml")

edits = 0

doc.xpath("//name").each do |name|
  if name.content == "?"
    name.content = name.xpath("following-sibling::address").text
    edits +=1
  end
end

puts( doc.inspect )
puts( "edits: #{edits}" )
puts doc
```

This gives me the following output:

```
#<Nokogiri::XML::Document:0xfe0064 name="document>
edits: 0
<?xml version="1.0"?>
```

If the `edits` testing code that I added works as I think it should, it seems to indicate that the `if name.content == "?"` block executed 0 times (about 130 fewer times than I intended).

Comment: [Nokogiri](http://nokogiri.org/).

Comment: Use XML parser for manipulating XML, like the one suggested by echoback.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know such a thing existed.  Reading the documentation now -- it looks like Nokogiri will have a solution.  I'll update here if I find one.

Comment: I think the fact that you are still fighting with this code trying to parse it is another good reason using a KML library just makes sense. Especially if new to KML/XML.

Comment: @SeamlessIan Since the `if name.content == "?"` always returns false, your document may not have what you think it does. Can you post a gist of an actual sample document?

Answer (score 3):

The work has been done for you for parsing / generating KML files in almost any language. I suspect this one will work for you: https://github.com/schleyfox/ruby_kml

**UPDATE**

Having not actually used the above library I wanted to confirm my recommendation - looks like all the helper functions are there for creating KML files, but will still require you to use an XML parser to load one. I would still suggest this is better than just manipulating you KML using an XML parser as suggested (although this will certainly work fine as well), but you might want to also look at http://georuby.rubyforge.org/georuby-doc/index.html which does support KML input and output.

**UPDATE 2** - Adding for posterity.

Putting some more thought into my answer, my default recommendation on issues like this is to:

1. Parse the KML into objects
2. Correct errors
3. Regenerate the KML

My reasoning is this *should* be less prone to trashing the output, and if you eventually start doing more manipulation of the KML you are already 90% of the way there.

All of this said, in your specific case, to make only the change you identify on known data, the approach by @Mark Thomas will provide a speedier and low code overhead solution.

Comment: While I agree in general that a KML parser/generator is better than rolling one by hand with an XML parser, I'm not sure a KML parser would solve the data quality issue at hand.

Comment: My approach would be to parse the KML into objects using the georuby library, iterate the list correcting the data issues, then output the results. That said, and as you laid out, it is a pretty simple XPath solution, and this might be overkill, until you need or want to make another change (maybe apply a conditional style, etc.)

Answer (score 2):

I recommend using an XML parser instead. This is some sample Nokogiri code:

```
doc = Nokogiri::XML(kml)

doc.xpath("//name").each do |name|
  if name.content == "?"
    name.content = name.xpath("following-sibling::address").text
  end
end
```

---

**UPDATE**

Based on your update, it appears something went wrong with the parsing of your XML file--are you sure it's valid?

Here's a complete working example:

```
require 'nokogiri'

xml = <<End
<Placemark>
  <name>?</name>
    <Snippet></Snippet>
    <description><![CDATA[]]></description>
    <styleUrl>#style75</styleUrl>
    <address>1234 Example St Denver, CO 80221</address>
    <Point>
      <coordinates>-121.879364,37.815151,0.000000</coordinates>
    </Point>
</Placemark>

End

doc = Nokogiri::XML(xml)

doc.xpath("//name").each do |name|
  if name.content == "?"
    name.content = name.xpath("following-sibling::address").text
  end
end

puts doc
```

Output:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<Placemark>
  <name>1234 Example St Denver, CO 80221</name>
    <Snippet/>
    <description/>
    <styleUrl>#style75</styleUrl>
    <address>1234 Example St Denver, CO 80221</address>
    <Point>
      <coordinates>-121.879364,37.815151,0.000000</coordinates>
    </Point>
</Placemark>
```

Comment: I tried running this and it executed without errors, but nothing seemed to change within the document.  I then modified it as follows to see whether or not the code block was being run:

Comment: Did you output the new doc? Try `puts doc`.

Comment: Please see update above, showing the code I ran and the result.

Comment: What did your xml file contain? When you print it out, it's empty. My sample code works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Let's try using this:

```
require 'nokogiri'

doc = Nokogiri::XML::DocumentFragment.parse(<<EOT)
<Placemark>
  <name>?</name>
  <Snippet></Snippet>
  <description><![CDATA[]]></description>
  <styleUrl>#style75</styleUrl>
  <address>1234 Example St Denver, CO 80221</address>
  <Point>
    <coordinates>-121.879364,37.815151,0.000000</coordinates>
  </Point>
</Placemark>
EOT

doc.search('Placemark').each do |placemark|
  name = placemark.at('name')
  address = placemark.at('address')
  name.content = address.text
end

puts doc.to_xml
```

Which outputs:

```
<Placemark>
  <name>1234 Example St Denver, CO 80221</name>
  <Snippet/>
  <description><![CDATA[]]></description>
  <styleUrl>#style75</styleUrl>
  <address>1234 Example St Denver, CO 80221</address>
  <Point>
    <coordinates>-121.879364,37.815151,0.000000</coordinates>
  </Point>
</Placemark>
```

I used a document fragment to avoid adding extraneous content. Normally you'd want to use the normal `Nokogiri::XML` to parse the document.

I'm assuming you have more than one `<Placemark>` tag, which `search` will iterate over, returning a NodeSet.